Tao Analysis I Ex 3.5.7 asking us to see patterns in cartesian products, subsets, intersection and union
This question is about the last part of Tao's Analysis I 4th ed ex 3.5.7:

Let $X$, $Y$ be sets, and let $\pi_{X \times Y \to X}:X \times Y \to X$ and $\pi_{X \times Y \to Y}:X \times Y \to Y$ be the maps $\pi_{X \times Y \to X} (x, y) := x$ and $\pi_{X \times Y \to Y}(x, y) := y$; these maps are known as the co-ordinate functions on $X × Y$. Show that for any functions $f : Z \to X$ and $g : Z \to Y$, there exists a unique function $h:Z \to X \times Y$ such that $\pi_{X \times Y \to X} \circ h= f$ and $\pi_{X \times Y \to Y} \circ h=g$. (Compare this to the last part of Exercise 3.3.8, and to Exercise 3.1.7.) This function $h$ is known as the pairing of $f$ and $g$ and is denoted $h = (f, g)$.

(see below for copies of ex 3.3.8 and 3.1.7)

I am not sure sure what he wants us to see, but I have drawn pictures which I think show a duality or symmetry between these relations:

Here we can see there is a duality between the existence of a unique function that maps to $X \times Y$ in the first instance, and maps from $X \cup Y$ in the second.

And here we can see similar duality regarding intersection and union where the function is replaced by a predicate "is a subset of".
Is this what Tao wanted us to see?

For reference:
Ex 3.3.8 (d)

(d) Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint sets, and $f : X \to Z$ and $g: Y \to Z$ are functions, then there is a unique function $h: X∪Y \to Z$ such that $h \circ \iota_{X \to X \cup Y} =f$ and $h \circ \iota_{Y\to X \cup Y} =g$.

Ex 3.1.7

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be sets. Show that $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and $A \cap B \subseteq B$. Furthermore, show that $C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$ if and only if $C \subseteq A \cap B$. In a similar spirit, show that $A \subseteq A \cup B$ and $B \subseteq A \cup B$, and furthermore that $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$ if and only if $A \cup B \subseteq C$.


If you are familiar with categories then binary products and co-products can be recognized in two categories that both have sets as objects. The first is the usual one having functions $A\to B$ as morphisms from $A\to B$. In the second there is at most one morphism $A\to B$ which exists iff $A\subseteq B$.

hi @drhab I'm afraid I don't know category theory, and I suspect Terence Tao doesn't expect his readers to either as his book is a beginner introduction. Is what I have written / drawn a correct interpretation (or special case) of the category theory you describe? Thanks again for your input.

I have the impression that you did fine (though I miss the context of Tao's book). You observed duality (in categories a very important concept) and similarity (in both cases we see the same concepts and they are dual wrt of eachother).
